# Interpolate from one grid to another in python

Tags: python, dictionary, grid, coordinates, interpolation

I have spent now several weeks on a problem I really think must have an easy answer.

I have data in the form of

```
lat1.shape=[26,32]
lon1.shape=[26,32]
data1.shape=[26,32]
```

which is a coarse grid (resolution 12.5x12.5km)

I have another dataset in the form of

```
lat2.shape=[103, 127]
lon2.shape=[103, 127]
data2.shape=[103, 127]
```

which is a finer grid (3.125x3.125 km)

Now, I want to make a calculation involving both and for this I would like to interpolate the coarser grid on the finer grid, to have then the same dimensions and same grid-points.
Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the internet involving these 2D-coordinates.
I already tried griddata, basemap.interp and interp2d. Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you so much for any help !

Answer (score 2):

For each of your variables separately: lat, lon, data, try this,

1. Since your data is on a regular grid use [RectBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html)
2. Evaluate the interpolant on the finer grid